# Is polyurethane too slippery to use as a protective layer on a deck?

Tags: polyurethane

I am in the process of repainting my deck.  I'd like to have a protective layer (like clearcoat on a car) that will allow easier cleanup, and would help to pretect the new paint.  Is polyurethane appropriate for the job?

Comment: Polyurethane will not hold up to sunlight.

Comment: That is nonsense. There are aliphatic polyurethanes which hold up to UV (for instance made from HDI: hexamethylene diisocyanate), and there are aromatic polyurethanes which don't, like those made with TDI (toluene diisocyanate).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is Spar Urethane. Polyurethane is not good for outdoor use. Spar urethane will hold up the UV rays better.

Comment: isn't spar urethane even more slippery than polyurethane?

Answer (score 2):

I don't ever like film finishes (whether paint or poly or varnishes) for horizontal exterior surfaces.  Water and sun will win.  Then you must remove chipped paint/finish before renewing

The use of penetrating transparent or semi-opaque exterior rated stains, will breath and last longer.  Overcoats can be made after washing and drying the surface.

Answer (score 2):

There are additives you can add to a floor coating which reduce slipperiness, such as polypropylene beads.